# How to add multiple affiliations (institutes) to one single author in beamer class?

Tags: beamer, titles, affiliation

I am using the *beamer* class to produce a presentation out of it. Now I want to assign multiple affiliations to one author. Until now, I tried something like this:

```
\author{author1\inst{1}$^{,}$\inst{2}}
```

which works fine except that in this way your author will be shown as its name with a "," as a superscript. You see this for example in the footline.

What would be a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile I found a very straight forward approach by try and error. Multiple affiliations can just be included by using a `comma` inside of the `\inst` command. For my example, it would look like this:

```
\author{author1\inst{1,2}}
```

Sometimes, the world can be very easy...

Answer (score 3):

I think `beameruserguide` (Section 10.1: Adding a title Page, page 87) shows a good solution.

```
\author[author1]{author1\inst{1}$^{,}$\inst{2}}
```

The `short author name` (which is in between `[...]`) will be shown in footline.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{This is a presentation}
\author[Me]{Author\inst{first institute}$^{,}$\inst{second institute}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{First frame}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]